# white screen on macbook pro noise when keys are pressed

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

my macsbooks screen turned white yesterday, the keys were making sounds when pressed. I have plugged my mac in to my tv and the screen comes up on my tv, but the laptop screen is still blank. please help

Answer (score 1):

You might have the display brightness completely turned off, so press whatever key increases brightness, like F2 on my mid-2009 MacBook Pro.

If that doesn't work, it sounds like a bad display to me. Find a professional electronic repair technician in your area to fix, and be prepared to spend $200-$300+ on the repair as the display assembly isn't cheap.